# How to align elements in Bootstrap columns, across browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, css-transforms

I have images centered (and layered) dead-center of the screen, and a sticky nav under the images. It works PERFECT in Chrome, but not in IE or Firefox.

What am I missing?

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="eventWrapper">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="hero">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/00f" class="eventHeroImg imgFire">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/fff" class="eventHeroImg imgLight">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/f00" class="eventHeroImg imgChange">
      </div><!--/hero-->
    </div><!--/col-6-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="hero">
        <div class="solgan-column">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/f00" class="eventHeroImgimgFire">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/fff" class="eventHeroImg imgLight">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/00f" class="eventHeroImg imgChange">          
        </div><!--/slogan-column-->
       </div><!--/hero-->
    </div><!--/col-6-->
  </div><!--/wrapper-->
</div><!--/row-->

<!--
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="fullwidth_header_scroll">
      <a href="#nav">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down fa-3x centerArrowBottom wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1.5s" data-wow-duration="2s"></i>
      </a>
    </div><!--/fullwidth--> 
  </div><!--/12-->
</div><!--/row-->




<ul id="nav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#top">Top</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sponsorship">something</a></li>
</ul>


<script src="https://wowjs.uk/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     new WOW().init();
    </script>
```

And here's the CSS

```
html {scroll-behavior: smooth}

body {
  font-size: 16px; margin: 0;
}

ul#nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

ul#nav li {
  float: left;
}

ul#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000066;
}

.hero {
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
  }

img.eventHeroImg, .solgan-column {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.imgLight {
  z-index: 3;
}
.imgChange {
  z-index: 5;
}

.imgFire {
  z-index: 1;
}



.centerArrowBottom {margin: auto !important;
    color: white;
  vertical-align: baseline;}

.fullwidth_header_scroll {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;

}

a.fullwidth_header_scroll {scroll-behavior: smooth;}

.centerArrowBottom:hover {
  color: darken(#00f, 10%)
}

.eventWrapper {background-image: url("http://eskipaper.com/images/beach-background-4.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;}

.slogan {color: goldenrod; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-family: 'Oswald'; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold; }
.slogan-left {float: left}
.slogan-right {float: right}
.heroEventInfo {font-family: 'Raleway'; font-size: 125%}
```

[Here's my codepen](https://codepen.io/SnowboardBruin/pen/KEZowB)

Here's with Chrome (PERFECT)
[image: Here's with Chrome (PERFECT)]

And here's with IE/Firefox (SUCKS)
[image: And here's with IE/Firefox (SUCKS)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because of lack of cross browser support for CSS property - `fill-available`. You can check the support matrix here: https://caniuse.com/#search=fill-available.

You have used `-webkit-fill-available`, which only Webkit browsers (chrome/safari) will support. For firexfox, it uses `-moz-available`.

Instead you can use `100vh` for specifying `height` or `min-height` to 100% of the screen. I have modified the code accordingly, and its working in both chrome and firefox.

Please check codepen link: https://codepen.io/rhythm19/pen/BbrjNV

Answer (score 1):

used `height: 500px` in-place of `height: -webkit-fill-available;` to .`hero` class. and removed height of `.eventWrapper`  as `height: -webkit-fill-available;` is will only work on chrome firefox doesn't know what webkit is. hope this helps and added `clearfix` class to `eventWrapper`  div. thanks

check below link. https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/KEopEv

Answer (score 0):

I have added a comment /*Modified code*/ please check that part
Also i have changed html structure little bit please check

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px; margin: 0;
}


ul#nav li {
  float: left;
}

ul#nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000066;
}

img.eventHeroImg, .solgan-column {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.imgLight {
  z-index: 3;
}
.imgChange {
  z-index: 5;
}

.imgFire {
  z-index: 1;
}
.centerArrowBottom {margin: auto !important;
    color: white;
  vertical-align: baseline;}

.fullwidth_header_scroll {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.fullwidth_header_scroll {scroll-behavior: smooth;}

.centerArrowBottom:hover {
  color: darken(#00f, 10%)
}

.slogan {color: goldenrod; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-family: 'Oswald'; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold; }
.slogan-left {float: left}
.slogan-right {float: right}
.heroEventInfo {font-family: 'Raleway'; font-size: 125%}

/*Modified code*/
.hero {
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 100px;
}

ul#nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
.eventWrapper {
 background-image: url("http://eskipaper.com/images/beach-background-4.jpg");
 background-size: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}
/*Modified code end*/
```

```html
<div class="eventWrapper"> <!-- Slight change here -->
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="hero">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/00f" class="eventHeroImg imgFire">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/fff" class="eventHeroImg imgLight">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/f00" class="eventHeroImg imgChange">
   </div><!--/hero-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="hero">
    <div class="solgan-column">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300/f00" class="eventHeroImgimgFire">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/fff" class="eventHeroImg imgLight">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100/00f" class="eventHeroImg imgChange">          
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<ul id="nav">
 <li><a class="active" href="#top">Top</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#sponsorship">something</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ul#nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
.hero {
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 100px;
}
.eventWrapper {
 background-image: url("http://eskipaper.com/images/beach-background-4.jpg");
 background-size: 100%;
 height: -webkit-fill-available;
 height: 100vh;
}

Comment: in the description.. not in the comment.

Comment: please check my updated code and description @XenioGracias